# getting all assessed properties in a view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

so I have a need of creating some complex caching system when I need to know every item that was used in a view right now I am getting this data from controller but its look ugly and creating a fat controllers like:

```
        $post = $this->repository->byId(1);
        CacheManager::addTags($post->comments);
        foreach ($post->comments as $comment) {
            CacheManager::addTags([$comment, $comment->user]);
        }
        foreach ($post->photos as $photo) {
            foreach ($photo->types as $type) {
                CacheManager::addTags([$type->id]);
            }
        }
```

so I was thinking is there some clever way of getting all the data that was used in a view?
like getting all this calls

```
{{$post->comment->id}}
```

so I will know that a comment was used in the view and insert it into the CacheManager

Comment: Have you tried eager loading?

Comment: you mean the relations? they eager loaded inside the repository but I need to get the id of all the relations and sub relations

Comment: Did you try `$post->comments->pluck('id')`?

Comment: yes but there is multiple relations and each relation has multipile subrelation so again I am ending with fat controllers